# Async await function is not getting called using jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am new to jest and i am trying to call await function it return the promise. But i am getting and error like expected calls 1 and received calls is 0

**Code:**

```
public async callDataSourceCommand(dialogData: any, RecipeId: string) {

   const gridItems = await this.dataSourceService.myPromiseMethod(id, collection);

}
```

**MockData**

```
 public get dataSourceServiceMock(): any = {
     return {
        myPromiseMethod: function () {
            return Promise.resolve({
                id: '123',
                collection: []
              });
        }
    }
}
```

**Test suite**

```
it('1. Should execute ', async() => {
    const myDialogApp: DialogApp = TestBed.get(DialogApp);
    myDialogApp.selectedOrder = selectedOrder;
    myDialogApp.RecipeId = Recipe.__id;
    myDialogApp.callDataSourceCommand(dialogData, RecipeId);
    jest.spyOn(dataSourceServiceMock, 'myPromiseMethod');
    expect(dataSourceServiceMock.myPromiseMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

After adding shuan's comment, still i am facing an issue is like,

console.error node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:703
      Unhandled Promise rejection: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
          at JSON.parse ()
          at OrderManagementMultipleBatchesDialogApp. (D:\DCS_WorkSpace\src\DCSPlus\UI\libs\order-management\apps\src\components\order-management-multiple-batches-dialog-app\order-management-multiple-ba
tches-dialog-app.factory.ts:102:30)

i have updated the test case

**MockData**

```
 public get dataSourceServiceMock(): any = {
     return {
        myPromiseMethod: function () {
            return Promise.resolve({
                 selectedOrder: {
                    earlierStartTime: '2/5/2020',
                   __id: 'orderId123'
                },
            batchCollection: {
                  __id: 'b1order 1',
                  masterRecipeName: 'New recipe_V1.0',
                  plannedQuantity: '3',
                  masterRecipeId: 'ns=6;s=4/ProjectData/1',
                  actualQuantity: '1',
                  description: 'batchDesc',
                }
              });
        }
    }
}
```

**Test suite**

```
it('1. Should execute ', async() => {

    const myDialogApp: DialogApp = TestBed.get(DialogApp);
    myDialogApp.selectedOrder = selectedOrder;
    myDialogApp.RecipeId = Recipe.__id;

    jest.spyOn(dataSourceServiceMock, 'myPromiseMethod');

    await myDialogApp.callDataSourceCommand(multipleBatchData, masterRecipeId);

    expect(dataSourceServiceMock.myPromiseMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: it's odd seeing a call to an asynchronous function - i.e. `myDialogApp.callDataSourceCommand(dialogData, RecipeId);` that isn't awaited - are you sure you know how to use async/await?

Answer (score 2):

As Jaromanda correctly wrote, you need to `await` the asynchronous method. Also, you need to spy on the method before acting not after acting.

Here is a simplified, standalone version of your original example that you can run in Jest.

```
class MyDialogApp {
  constructor(private dataSourceService: any) {}

  public async callDataSourceCommand() {
    await this.dataSourceService.myPromiseMethod();
  }
}

const dataSourceServiceMock = {
  myPromiseMethod: function() {
    return Promise.resolve({
      id: '123',
      collection: []
    });
  }
};

const myDialogApp = new MyDialogApp(dataSourceServiceMock);

it('1. Should execute ', async () => {
  // arrange
  jest.spyOn(dataSourceServiceMock, 'myPromiseMethod');

  // act
  await myDialogApp.callDataSourceCommand();

  // assert
  expect(dataSourceServiceMock.myPromiseMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Hi Shuan, Thanks for your reply. i have updated your changes. still i am facing the issue reported above. can you help me out to solve this

Comment: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse () at OrderManagementMultipleBatchesDialogApp. (D:\DCS_WorkSpace\src\DCSPlus\UI\libs\order-management\apps\src\components\order-management-multiple-batches-dialog-app\order-management-multiple-ba tches-dialog-app.factory.ts:102:30)